# How to databind two tables in GridView?

Tags: wpf, sqlite, data-binding, mvvm-light, observablecollection

Basically, I need to join two `ObservableCollections`, like for example a `Product` and `BrandInfo` where the `Product` model has an unofficially defined `foreign key` to `BrandInfo`. These models are using `Sqlite-Net` for data persistence.

I want to display the combination of the two in a `GridView`, which will be the basis of future data manipulation on other `Xaml` screens.

My current setup has data bound through a `viewModel` class, acquiring data via the `Product` model. The `viewModel` has an `ObservableCollection` instance of `Product`, and properly works.

From what I read, I may need to use `CompositeCollection` or possibly create a model that represents the `join` of `Product` and `BrandInfo`. Considering `Sqlite-Net` doesn't support foreign keys like `Entity Framework` and other `ORM's` do, I'm not really sure how to go about using `CompositeCollection`. I'm also not sure if doing a not-database-stored combination of the two models is a good idea or not. Any advice or snippets can go a long way in helping me out!

Thanks in advance!

Some code:

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using StoreFront.Models;
using StoreFront.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace StoreFront.ViewModels {
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase,IMainViewModel {

        private IDataService dataService;

        IDialogService dialogService;
        IStorageService storageService;

        public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService, IStorageService storageService) {
            this.dataService = dataService;
            this.storageService = storageService; 

            RefreshAsync(); //Basically fills the product ObservableCollection with data.
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Product> product = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        public ObservableCollection<Product> Product {
            get {
                return product;
            }
        }

}
```

**Product.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SQLite;

namespace StoreFront.Models {
    public class Product {

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set;}

        public string ItemName { get; set;}

        public double Price { get; set;}

        public int BrandInfoFK { get; set;}    
    }
}
```

**BrandInfo.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SQLite;

namespace StoreFront.Models {
    public class BrandInfo {

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set;}

        public string BrandName { get; set;}

        public string Description { get; set;} 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDIT* initial answer I had was completely based on a misinterpretation of question.

Since I'm not familiar with SQLite, I'm not sure if your Product and BrandInfo models are created by code generation or manually created. If manually created, would you be able to add the BrandInfo properties to Product? If possible, you can use linq to join your collections of product and brandinfo models to create a collection you can bind to in your GridView:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>() { new Product() {Id = 1, ItemName="Item1", BrandInfoFK=1}, new Product() {Id=2, ItemName="Item2", BrandInfoFK=2}};
    List<BrandInfo> brands = new List<BrandInfo>() { new BrandInfo() { Id = 1, BrandName="One"}, new BrandInfo() {Id = 2, BrandName="Two"}};


    List<Product> joinedProducts = products.Join(brands, p => p.BrandInfoFK, b => b.Id, (p, b) => new Product ()
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        ItemName = p.ItemName,
        Price = p.Price,
        BrandInfoFK = p.BrandInfoFK,
        BrandName = b.BrandName,
        BrandDescription = b.Description
    }).ToList();
}


public class Product {

    public int Id { get; set;}

    public string ItemName { get; set;}

    public double Price { get; set;}

    public int BrandInfoFK { get; set;}    

    // Brand properties
    public string BrandName {get; set;}

    public string BrandDescription {get; set;}
}

public class BrandInfo {
    public int Id { get; set;}

    public string BrandName { get; set;}

    public string Description { get; set;} 
}
```

I'm using List's here, but you can easily adapt to ObservableCollection's. Also, if you cannot/don't want to add the BrandInfo properties into your Product model, you can maybe create a class derived from Product that adds these properties?

Comment: The way I understand viewModels are used are in relation to the UI, not necessarily the Models. What I mean is there's generally a 1-to-1 ratio with your UI and ViewModels (i.e. `MainWindowViewModel` and `DetailsViewModel` with `MainWindow.xaml` and `DetailsWindow.xaml`). That tidbit of info is what Laurent, the creator of MVVM-Light, had said in his PluralSight lectures.

That being said, I'm up for anything if there's an example I could see. I'll try adding some code for reference. I apologize for not doing so earlier.

Comment: @Steven_BDawg I don't disagree with anything you said :). Now that you put in your code, I think I completely misread your question in terms of what you wanted to represent when you said you wanted to display a combination of the items. Do you basically want to display a grid with a product per row, with columns representing "ItemName", "price", "BrandName", and "Description"? In other words, did you want to INNER JOIN the tables and put it in the grid?

Comment: Yes inner join with with the query result data bindable! :D

Comment: @Steven_BDawg Edited my answer. I think it should do what you want. You just have to have a reference to both your collection of brands and products at the time of populating your observablecollection in your MainViewModel

Comment: Hmm I didn't realize there's a List.join command... I'm going to try to implement it like you have it but create a combined class that isn't stored in Sqlite.

Comment: Something isn't right syntax wise. it's basically not letting me use those names in the .Join because they've been declared already (as lists above)...

Comment: @Steven_BDawg There shouldn't be any issues syntax wise. You can run my entire sample in linqpad. Which part of the Join are you referring to when you say "those names"? I'm going to edit my answer as well to use "p" and "b" instead of product and brand for more clarity as well.

Comment: AHA! i didn't realize the now-"p" and "b" weren't the original objects! I've never used .Join before. I'm setting it up now and trying to make it work with ObservableCollection. Thank you for the clarification. I believe I'm really close to having it work....

Comment: Thanks Rowbear for the redo and then the clarification edits you did! :) It works in my existing code!! My code is actually more detailed than this, but the scope I needed help with, you answered! :D